# Arraylist item does not take a string as an input error code : CS0029

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
ArrayList a = new ArrayList();

a[i] = txtSifre.Text; //ERROR CS0029
```

I want to store the string data that is coming from a textbox into an ArrayList. However, I face with an convertion error : cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'system.collections.arraylist' in C#

Here is the FULL code :

```
int i = 0;
        ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
        private void btnEkle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Hashtable openwith = new Hashtable();
            openwith.Add(txtKullaniciAdi.Text, txtSifre.Text);

            foreach (var item in openwith)
            {
                foreach (DictionaryEntry de in openwith)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add($"User Name : {de.Key} \t Password : {de.Value}");
                }
            }

            a[i] = txtSifre.Text; //ERROR CS0029 !!
            if(i>=1)
            {
                for (int J = 1; J < 2; J++)
                {
                    if (a[J - 1].ToString() == a[J].ToString())
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("You can not enter the same password again!!");
                    }
                }
            }
            i++;

            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't use ArrayList, use List<string> instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/when-to-use-generic-collections

Comment: Also `ArrayList[] a = new ArrayList();` will not compile at all

Comment: for (int J = 1; J < 2; J++)
This line of code will only every run once, comparing a[0] to [a[1].

Answer (score 0):

As Martheen mentions, it would be better to use List.

Example:

```cs
var a = new List<string>();

a.Add(txtSifre.Text);
```

However, I will concern myself with certain points as well.

**1. Double `foreach` on `openwith`**

I think the first loop is useless, you can delete it, without deleting its content of course.

```cs
            //foreach (var item in openwith) //DELETE THIS
            //{
                foreach (DictionaryEntry de in openwith)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add($"User Name : {de.Key} \t Password : {de.Value}");
                }
            //}
```

**2. If/Foreach block**

```cs
            if(i>=1)
            {
                for (int J = 1; J < 2; J++)
                {
                    if (a[J - 1].ToString() == a[J].ToString())
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("You can not enter the same password again!!");
                    }
                }
            }
```

It seems quite complex to me for not much, but it is possible that I do not understand all of what you are trying to do.

Here I will give you more suggestions:

- You can use `List.Count` property to count the number of items in a list.

Example: `if (a.Count > 1) { ... }`

- You can use `List.Contains` method for check if item is in the list.

Example: `if (a.Contains(txtSifre.Text)) { ... }`

Hoping to have helped you.